# Flag Question Link After 3k Rep

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I noticed from a question about flagging vs closing (forgive me, I cannot find the link, please post it if you know it), that flags are CONVERTED into close votes for questions automatically. Can somebody confirm this?

If confirmed, I was wondering why the link (again, for questions only) is simply not removed to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> that flags are CONVERTED into close votes for questions automatically

Yes, if you click on the "flag" link and then on "it's a duplicate" or "it should be closed for another reason", then this flag will count as a close vote if you have 3k+:
[image: Flag dialog]

[image: Close vote dialog]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but do you know why it is like this instead of removing the link?

Comment: @RUJordan: If you have 3k+, you still need to be able to flag questions as spam, VLQ or mod attention.

Comment: The other reasons are basically recommendation for *deletion*, not closure. Those aren't present on the close menu.

Comment: Didn't even think of that. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

If you flag to close your flag is converted into a close vote, but there are other reasons to flag: the post is spam or offensive, or you need a way to flag the user (custom flag), for example.  Therefore the flag link needs to remain.

Given the existnce of the flag link, why not modify the dialogue to take away the close option?  Because that would mean specializing the code for one use case and any specialization adds a little complexity and fragility.  There's nothing really *wrong* with a close flag being converted to a vote on your behalf.  Why add complexity to address something that isn't doing anything that's really wrong?